# Not being able to simulate change on input and call onChange function using both shallow and mount. Enzyme, jestjs, react

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, jsdom

This is not a duplicate question because non of them worked for me and they were doing something different as well.

I have a component of email and password with form validation and now I want to do unit testing, and i want to simulate change on input but i am not able to do it. I have tried both shallow and mount i didn't try render but it wouldn't work either i read it in some documentations. I read somewhere that functions are needed to be binded or something but i am new to testing so i don't know much. This question might be super easy but i have been working on it for hours and i need to get it done. So please guide me and also suggest me if what i am doing is optimal or not.

*sign-in.test.jsx*

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { findByTestAttr } from "../../Utils/testUtils.js";

import SignIn from "./sign-in.component";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  email: "",
  password: "",
  rememberme: false,
  emailErr: "",
  passwordErr: "",
  buttonErr: "",
  progressBar: 0,
  disable: true,
};

const setUp = (props = {}) => {
  const component = shallow(<SignIn />); // Have also done like this: mount(<BrowserRouter><SignIn /><BrowserRouter />)
  return component;
};

//Issue is with the last test case but feel free to suggest me about other tests as well

describe("Sign in component should render ", () => {
  let component;
  beforeEach(() => {
    component = setUp();
  });
  test("Email input field", () => {
    const wrapper = findByTestAttr(component, "email");
    expect(wrapper.length).toBe(1);
  });
  test("It should render password input field", () => {
    const wrapper = findByTestAttr(component, "password");
    expect(wrapper.length).toBe(1);
  });
  test("It should render a remember me checkbox", () => {
    const wrapper = findByTestAttr(component, "remember-me");
    expect(wrapper.length).toBe(1);
  });
  test("It should render a forget password link", () => {
    const wrapper = findByTestAttr(component, "forget-password");
    expect(wrapper.length).toBe(1);
  });
  test("It should render a sign in button", () => {
    const wrapper = findByTestAttr(component, "sign-in");
    expect(wrapper.length).toBe(1);
  });
  test("It should render a google sign in button", () => {
    const wrapper = findByTestAttr(component, "google-sign-in");
    expect(wrapper.length).toBe(1);
  });
  test("It should render a facebook sign in button", () => {
    const wrapper = findByTestAttr(component, "facebook-sign-in");
    expect(wrapper.length).toBe(1);
  });
});

describe("Form validation with different values", () => {
  let component;
  beforeEach(() => {
    component = setUp();
  });
  test("Form values", () => {
    const input = component.find(".email").at(0);

    input.simulate("change", { target: { value: "check" } });
    console.log(component.state.email); //undefined
  });
});
```

*sign-in.component.jsx*

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import CustomButton from "../../components/custom-button/custom-button.component";
import CompanyLogo from "../../components/company-logo-header/company-logo-header.component";
import InputField from "../../components/input-field/input-field.component";
import InputError from "../../components/input-field-error/input-field-error.component";
import { mailFormat, passwordFormat } from "../../Utils/regularExpressions";
import "./sign-in.styles.scss";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  email: "",
  password: "",
  rememberme: false,
  emailErr: "",
  passwordErr: "",
  buttonErr: "",
  progressBar: 0,
  disable: true,
};

class SignIn extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = INITIAL_STATE;
  }
  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
    const isValid = this.validate();
    if (isValid) {
      this.setState({ disable: false });
    } else {
      this.setState({ disable: true });
    }
  };
  validate = () => {
    let emailErr = "";
    let passwordErr = "";

    if (!this.state.email.match(mailFormat)) {
      emailErr = "Please enter a valid email format";
    }
    if (!this.state.password.match(passwordFormat)) {
      passwordErr = "Password should be eight digit with letters and numbers";
    }
    if (emailErr || passwordErr) {
      this.setState({
        emailErr,
        passwordErr,
      });
      return false;
    }
    this.setState({
      emailErr,
      passwordErr,
    });
    return true;
  };
  handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.disable) {
      await this.setState({
        buttonErr: "Please enter the email and password",
      });
      return;
    }
    const isValid = this.validate();
    if (isValid) {
      console.log(isValid);
      this.setState(INITIAL_STATE);
    }
  };
  render() {
    const { disable } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="sign-in">
        <CompanyLogo />
        <form noValidate className="sign-in-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <InputField
            name="email"
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email Address"
            data-test="email"
            className="email"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            value={this.state.email}
          />
          <InputError>{this.state.emailErr}</InputError>
          <InputField
            name="password"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            data-test="password"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            value={this.state.password}
          />
          <InputError>{this.state.passwordErr}</InputError>
          <div className="remember-forget">
            <span className="remember-me">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="rememberme"
                value="Remember Me"
                data-test="remember-me"
              />
              <label htmlFor="rememberme" className="rememberme">
                {" "}
                Remember me
              </label>
            </span>
            <Link
              to="password-reset"
              className="forgot-password"
              data-test="forget-password"
            >
              Forgot password?
            </Link>
          </div>
          <div className="center-buttons">
            <CustomButton
              data-test="sign-in"
              type="submit"
              SignIn
              disabled={disable}
            >
              Sign In
            </CustomButton>
            <InputError>{this.state.buttonErr}</InputError>
          </div>
          <div className="separator">Or</div>
          <div className="center-buttons">
            <CustomButton data-test="facebook-sign-in" type="button" Options>
              Sign in with facebook
            </CustomButton>
            <CustomButton data-test="google-sign-in" type="button" Options>
              Sign in with google
            </CustomButton>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SignIn;
```